# If there a way to have the current month by default in a KPI representing MoM% in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I hit a snag trying to put a quick measure (MoM%) in a KPI. When no filters are selected the KPI is showing me the month-on-month difference from Dec last year (2021) and Nov(2021) and not the current month Feb (2022) vs Jan(2022).
I have a calendar table and the measures are quite simple but I just can't make heads or tails of why I can't show the default value. I guess I have to add sth to the formula related to the filter context but not sure what. I leave a picture below so that you can see graphically what I mean.
I want the value in the red rectangle to be shown on the KPI not DEC last year. Thanks for your help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0tnH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to always see the last full month, you can use the `PREVIOUSMONTH` DAX function.
You can reference your measures with this new one and then just use this method with `ALL` in the filter index to ignore any filter that could be applied. Then you should be able to see the highest full month every time.